# Debian package project

Tags: shell

In school we had to choose a project in shell script. I have choose the 17th which is about listing Debian packages and solve some tasks with it but in school we didn't get any good advice or anything like that to start it and I would like to ask for some ideas how could I do it or even start it.

Some details about the project:

17. List of Debian packages:
    Under Debian, ask which packages are installed on the machine, enter the names of these packages in a formatted format, and the program will also write which programs a particular package depends on.
    For example.

```
nparted: libc6, libnewt0, libparted1.4, libuuid1
nano: libc6, libncurses5
```

I successfully did the package listing, but I don't know how could I move forward.

Comment: Learning how to search is an important skill to learn during your student age. For example, looking for `Debian show package dependency` is a good way to get yourself started.

Comment: Start reading the documentation for `dpkg-query`, `dpkg`, `apt-cache`, etc.  The act of reading the documentation to learn how to do specific tasks leads to much learning.  Filtering the output of the tools becomes an exercise in learning the right flags or passing output to `sed/awk`.

Answer (score 0):

`apt-cache depends <package>` shows the dependencies (`Depends`, `Recommends` and `Suggests`) of a package.

Alternatively, `apt show <package>` writes [the control file](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/deb-control.5.html) of a package.

The two commands have different output formats, so you can pick one that you find easier to parse.